# Proof that $n$ is a positive odd integer if $5n + 6$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples

Prove that $n$ is a positive odd integer if

$5n + 6 = 2k + 1$ or $(5n + 6) = 1\mod 2$

Comment: You ust have some ideas here, no?  To get started, since $n$ is odd we can write $n=2m+1$ for some integer $m$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. First of all try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question properly. Further questions of the type "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this website so make sure to add some details with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2937829/edit) like what have you tried, where do you stuck etc. :)

Comment: No, I'm being asked to prove n is odd so you are supposed to find out if n = 2m + 1 not assume that it is

Comment: Ok, fine.  Then work by contradiction.  Show that, if $n=2m$ then $5n+6$ is not odd.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback though. If i could've attached a photo of what I've done so far I would've

Comment: As the posted solutions are pointing out, your question is either unclear or incorrect.  If you mean "if $n$ is an integer such that $5n+6$ is odd, show that $n$ is odd,"  then it is correct and my suggestion will work.  If you want to show that $n$ is positive you'll need to know more.  If you don't assume that $n$ is an integer then it is false.  Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Thanks Lulu that's actually what I meant to say but we were asked to use a direct proof not a contrapositive one

Comment: Can you edit your post?  You left off a lot of critical things which are becoming clear in the comments...but not everybody will study the comments in detail, so the changes should be made in the post itself.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is wrong! Try $n=\frac{1}{5}.$

Comment: N has to be a whole number and I equated it to 2k + 1 because I'm to assume that 5n + 6 is odd

Comment: @Kwabena: That was not said in your question.

Comment: @Kwabena Read please the given again.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to prove is not true -- it fails, for example for $n=-1$.

$5\cdot(-1)+6 = 1$ which is odd, but $-1$ is *not* a positive odd integer.